# Getting access to loop variables

Tags: php, loops

I am not getting the information from the first loop into the second one it gives an error saying for example: **Notice: Undefined index: txtprice** in..
the issue is that I can't get the data from `if(isset($_POST['getdata']))` into `if(isset($_POST['addto']))` to echo it out and make calculations

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="newcal.php">

<table>
<tr>
 <td> Item #: </td>
 <td> <input type=text name= txtitem > <br> </td>
 
 <td>
 </td>
 <td> <fieldset style = "width:60px">
  <input type=submit value = "Get Data" name= getdata>
  <input type=submit value = "Add to Cart" name= addto>
  <input type=submit value = "Get Total" name= gettotal>
  </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
$item = (isset($_POST['txtitem']) ? intval($_POST['txtitem']) : null);


 $stuff = array(
    array("id" => 1,"name" => "Apples","price" => 50 ),
    array("id" => 2,"name" => "Pineapples","price" => 125 ),
    array("id" => 3,"name" => "Mango","price" => 35 ),
    array("id" => 4,"name" => "Banana","price" => 25 ),
    array("id" => 5,"name" => "Naseberry","price" => 38 ));
    

   if(isset($_POST['getdata']))
   {
   
    foreach ($stuff as $row) 
    {
     if ($row['id'] == $item) 
     {
     $name = $row['name'];
     $price = $row['price'];
     
     echo "Item Number:&nbsp &nbsp <input type=\"text\" name=\"txtinum\"  VALUE=\"$item\">"."</br>"."</br>";
     
     echo "Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type=\"text\" name=\"txtname\"  VALUE=\"$name\">"."</br>"."</br>";
     
     echo "Price : &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type=\"text\" name=\"txtprice\" VALUE=\"$price\">"."</br>"."</br>";
     
     echo "Quantity: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type=\"text\" name=\"txtquant\">"."</br>"."</br>"; 

     
     }
    }
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['addto']))
     {
     $quant = isset($_POST['txtquant']);
    $cal = $price * $quant;
 
       echo "<table width='360px' border='1' cellpadding='2'>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<th> Item ID</th>" ;
       echo "<th> Name</th>";
       echo"<th> Price</th>"; 
       echo"<th> Quantity</th>"; 
       echo"<th> Sub Total </th>";
       echo "</tr>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td> $itemnum </td>";
       echo "<td> $name </td>";
       echo "<td> $price </td>";
       echo "<td> $quant </td>";
       echo "<td>   </td>";
       echo "<tr>";

     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a textbox that was omitted from the code that accepts data from the user that part works i just cant get the values from the textbox from in in the first loop

Comment: There is no second loop in that code

Comment: if(isset($_POST['addto']))
that is the second loop

Comment: the issue is that i cant get the data from if(isset($_POST['getdata'])) into if(isset($_POST['addto'])) to echo it out and mke calculations

Comment: Post the actual error you are getting because the undefined index warning that you mention doesnt appear to belong to this code.  Also be more clear about what your problem is. Hint: there is only one loop in this code.

Comment: PS 1994 called, they want their HTML back.